how to display dependent drop down selected value in edit page in laravel
I want to dispaly my selected dependent dropdown value in in my input field .
I want to check that the dependent dropdown value is selected or not using if statement.If selected then display it on the input field.
the controller code is given below:-
public function editsub_category(Request $request)

You need to use AJAX. You will get plenty of resources online on this topic.

Please provide more context, and the full controller code, as say @Subha, you need call the back end part without reload the full page, this can be done with AJAX, but it is 2024, you can acomplish this with a lot of tools: livewire, vue, jquery...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
